# Import CSV file and generate ddl command into database using java

Tags: java, oracle

I need logic how to read CSV file and generate ddl command into database using java

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the csv file format? What DDL you want to generate?

Comment: I have metadata CSV file I need to add this metadata into new database schema using java code i am unable to create the logic could you please help me

Comment: Can _you_ write code when you no nothing about the inputs or outputs?